# Inject jQuery, jQuery UI and plugins without version conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I would like to inject, via a bookmarklet, my own code into a web page.
That code needs jQuery, jQuery UI and some plugins to be added too in the web page.

I read about `noConflict` but what about if some jQuery plugins (with different version) are also loaded by the web page and they uses the same CSS class names or ids.

how must I proceed to inject all my code?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of bookmarklet are you trying to inject. If you can open an iframe using your bookmarklet and show your content there like RTM, Springpad etc then I believe you won't have a problem.

Comment: No, I need to inject code to show floating window, buttons, etc

Comment: IMHO, it would be better to use plain javascript for floating window. If you can have an iframe then, i believe, that you can use jquery and other stuff.